# Where DebugKit should be in 3.x?

Tags: cakephp, plugins, path, cakephp-3.x

I'm wondering where debugkit should be in 3.x because I wonder if it's location didn't change from beta version.

So I now have 3 locations:

`App/plugins/DebugKit`
`App/vendor/cakephp/debug_kit`
`App/vendor/cakephp/plugins/DebugKit`

Currently, it seems my install uses `App/plugins/DebugKit` but composer updates `App/vendor/cakephp/debug_kit` so I'm a bit lost

Answer (score 1):

The first path, ie the `plugins` folder, is the place where non-composer and first party plugins that are tied to your application may go.

The second path, ie the `vendors` folder, is for composer installable plugins.

The third path looks just wrong, not sure if this stems from a pre-stable release, but I'm pretty sure that this is not used anymore.

So, keep the second one, ditch the others, and you should be good. In case you have references to the old paths in your `composer.json` file, you should remove them and re-dump the autoloader

```
composer dump-autoload
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Plugins > Installing a Plugin With Composer](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#installing-a-plugin-with-composer)**
- **[Cookbook > Plugins > Loading a Plugin > Autoloading Plugin Classes](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#autoloading-plugin-classes)**
- **https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload**

Comment: ok thanks but I suppose there something wrong in some config files as `Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => true]);` in bootstrap.php loads DebugKit from the first folder. if I rename it, i get `Failed opening '/App/plugins/DebugKit/config/bootstrap.php'`. Any idea?

Comment: @caBBAlainB "_as_"? As what?

Comment: I found that the probleme came from `autoload.php` in vendor directory. I don't know if it's normal this file has not be updated.

Comment: @caBBAlainB There isn't much to update in that file. If at all, the `vendor/composer/autoload_*.php` files need to be updated. If you had autoload references to the old paths in your `composer.json`, then you'd have to remove them, and re-dump the autoloader (`composer dump-autoload` **https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload**).